# Scripts loading problems?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

So I'm converting a html template to a wordpress theme, I've added all the specific tags in the index.php, footer.php, header.php, and style.css and it looks my scripts won't load properly. 
This is the site that I want to convert : http://iulian.cablevision.ro/rock4life/
I've instaled wordpress on my localhost to play in the sandbox. And I think the problem is withing the functions.php ? this is how my website loads: http://iulian.cablevision.ro/rock4life_wp/ . I also removed the loading screen at the begining because won't load the site at all... Inspecting whit firebug will show up no scripts. 
function.php file:

```
<?php

function firstwp_resources(){
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_uri());
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','firstwp_resources');

   function your_scripts() {
                    wp_register_script('jquery', 'js/jquery.js', true);
                    // This registers your script with a name so you can call it to enqueue it
                    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
                    // enqueuing your script ensures it will be inserted in the propoer place in the header section
                    wp_register_script('jquery.reveal', 'js/jquery.reveal.js', true);
                    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.reveal' );

                    wp_register_script('jquery.backstretch', 'js/jquery.backstretch.min.js', true);
                    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.backstretch');

                    wp_register_script('jquery.tweet', 'js/jquery.tweet.js', true);
                    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.tweet');

                    wp_register_script('mediaelement-and-player', 'js/mediaelement-and-player.min.js', true);
                    wp_enqueue_script('mediaelement-and-player');

                    wp_register_script('custom', 'js/custom.js', true);
                    wp_enqueue_script('custom');

                    wp_register_script('jquery.placeholder', 'js/jquery.placeholder.min.js', true);
                    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.placeholder');
            }
            add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_scripts');
            // This hook executes the enqueuing of your script at the proper moment.
```

Comment: Look at the documentation for wp_register_script(). (1) the second parameter should be a full URL; (2) WordPress pre-registers lots of standard scripts, for example jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make sure the scripts to load, and will make sure the scripts for the Dashboard to be safe.

```
<?php
function firstwp_resources() {
    if (!is_admin()) {

        // Default Scripts
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jquery.js', false, null);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

        wp_deregister_script('jquery-mig');
        wp_register_script('jquery-mig', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/jquery-mig.js', false, null);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-mig');

        // Other Scripts
        wp_enqueue_script('name', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/name.js', false, null, true); // loads in footer
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'firstwp_resources');
?>
```

[Default Scripts Included and Registered by WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress)